# referencing a source controlled project (using TFS) in another source controlled project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, reference

i have three VS solutions :
  Human-resource Solution
  Payroll Solution

And a Main web site (Shell);

Human-resource is a solution which is also a team project.

Payroll is the same, and so do the Main web Site(Shell).

what i need is to reference the (Shell) in Human-resource solution

and also in Payroll.

is that possible in TFS ?
and if so, if i modified the Shell in Human-Resource solution,
is the modifications transferred automatically to the Payroll Solution ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, go to File->Source Control->Add Project from Source Control...

This will pop up a dialog allowing you to add a project from elsewhere in source control.

Once you get into sharing projects like this, it's worthwhile getting a bit robust in your source control structure, so this is worth a read:

http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/wikipage

Comment: Each of these is in a separate team project, though.  So that's going to make the build a bit interesting.

Comment: thank you Jim, I'll read the article, it looks like exactly what I need,
and BTW I tried to build the structure that i mentioned,
it worked for a simple test,
but I'm wondering if there is any known issues for this !

Comment: The biggest issue is with sharing code in general and is the hardest to get into people's habits: Do not share unstable code.
Try to manage the shared projects as releases in their own right. Have each project reference a version that it knows is good for it, and explicitly upgrade to new versions when it's right for that project. Synchronise library versions manually and explicitly. In m yexperience not doing this leads quickly to fragile projects that everyone's scared to touch, and huge headaches as everyone runs around the office going 'is it ok if I make this change to this file', etc.

Comment: i have looked too long for this answer (like 90 minutes)... thanks man!

Comment: With Visual Studio 2012: File > Source Control > Advanced > Add Project from Source Control...

Comment: These days it might be a good idea to looking at publishing NuGet packages.

Comment: @JimT The link's broken.