# Checkout projects from different TFS locations into one VS solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

Is it possible to checkout projects from different team foundation server locations/projects into one solution in visual studio?

The reason I want to do this is that I have a custom library that I use in different projects. I want to build the project against the source code. That means if I change the library I don't have to add the new assembly by hand.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this the same way as you would locally: create the solution, add the existing project to it, and then check the solution in.  You can't mix different TFS servers in a single solution (as far as I'm aware), but you should be able to use (Visual Studio) projects from different TFS "Team Projects."

Answer (score 1):

Sure can see this answer:

[referencing a source controlled project (using TFS) in another source controlled project.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570635/referencing-a-source-controlled-project-using-tfs-in-another-source-controlled/3575978#3575978)